# Building strings using 2 CSV files with dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, csv, dictionary

I've been struggling for quite some time with this task and here I am asking for some guidance on how to approach my problem.

To give some context, I have about 60'000 files that I'm trying to reorganize. I have 2 CSV files that I'm going to use.

file1.csv

```
id |    path       | objectid | image path
 1 | path/to/file1 |   4123   | http://url./image1.jpg
 2 | path/to/file2 |   5111   | http://url./image2.jpg

...(about 60'000 rows)
```

file2.csv

```
objectid | categoryid | termid | Description | parent
  4123   |    8302    |  14    |  Category1  |   10
  4123   |    5123    |  66    |  Category2  |   14
```

So second file can have multiple rows with the same objectid's (in file1 there's only 1 per row). That makes subcategories available which are being created using parent -> termid. Categoryid is just the id for the name of the category but the parent columnn is looking at the termid to determine it's parent.

So what I'm trying to achieve is the following: Take the file path from file1.csv, by it's objectid find all the rows in file2.csv with the same objectid, sort them based on parent number (lower goes first) and prepend each of the descriptions on the correct order (separated with/) on the same line to the existing path from the file1. Ultimately it'll download an image from the same row and move it in filesystem but i'm struggling with getting the thing to make the filenames.

Here's the code what I have right now:

```
import csv

main_dict = {}
with open('files1.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            filepath = row[1]
            objectid = row[2]
            imagepath = "http://url.com" + row[3] + "_0001.jpg"
            key = row[2]
            main_dict[key] = row[1]
        #print(main_dict)

second_dict = {}
with open('file2.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            key = row[0]
            second_dict[key] = row[3]
        print(second_dict)

for key in main_dict:
    if key in second_dict:
        print(second_dict[key] + '/' + main_dict[key] )
```

I might be going in completely wrong direction with this so any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S I'm using Python3.5

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  Stack Overflow is for demonstrable problems with your code, not speculative implementation help.  You may want CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: This sounds like a very databasey solution, might a database be a better choice than csv files which you read in to memory?

Comment: Maybe… However this is a one time thing and I won't need to do this again later on… I do have the data in the database though…

Comment: Aside: please post data in its raw form.  Your examples use pipes, but your code uses the default comma separator.  Assuming that your data actually has commas, anyone who wants to use your examples as their input has to return them to the form you originally had them in. It also makes it difficult to know if you need to strip whitespace from values -- is it really there, or did you add it yourself for some reason?  Etc.

Comment: It's commas, I just used that as an example to draw out how the data looks like in a visual way…

Comment: @kokozz: can you see why that is actually counterproductive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most efficient way to accomplish this would be using pandas module as part of python's data analysis ecosystem. I am using python version 2.7 for the following code example to do what you are asking so you can try to port this for python 3.5 but should be straightforward.

Pandas use internal dataframe(shown as 'df' in code below) objects to store the tabular information

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\alii\Desktop\stackOF.csv") # file1
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\alii\Desktop\stackOF2.csv") # file2
```

<sub>df1 looks like this:</sub>

[image]

<sub>df2 looks like this:</sub>

[image]

```
df2 = df2.sort(['parent']) # sort by parent
df1 = df1.set_index(df1.objectid)
```

<sub>df1 looks like this:</sub>
[image]

```
df2['path'] = df2.objectid.map(df1.path) #add path for each objectid from file1
```

<sub>df2 looks like this:</sub>
[image]

```
s3 = df2.groupby('objectid').apply(lambda x: np.repeat(x['Description'].values, 1).tolist())
df2 = df2.set_index(df2.objectid)
df3 = s3.to_frame('Description')
df3 = df3.reset_index()
```

<sub>df3(new object) looks like this:</sub>

[image]

```
df3['path'] = df3.objectid.map(df2.drop_duplicates('objectid').path)
```

<sub>df3(new object) looks like this:</sub>
[image]

```
df3['Description'] = df3['Description'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x))
```

<sub>df3(new object) looks like this:</sub>
[image]

```
df3['Description'] = df3['Description'].astype(str) + str('/') +df3['path'].astype(str)
df3 = df3.drop('path', 1)
```

<sub>df3(new object) looks like this(final):</sub>

[image]

```
df3.to_csv('file3.csv')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Imran! This definitely solves that, I'm gonna pipe that in to variable and use it to move the files. One question though and I think the solution is in this line:  df2['Description'] = df2['Description'].astype(str) + str('/') +df2['path'].astype(str). It only takes 2 parameters instead of all of them. If you use look up for an objectid in second file it'll return more than 2 categories, usually 4-5 and the path should be constructed using those- lowest first and up to the highest. Is that possible?

Comment: Please accept my answer and also upvote if its acceptable. The line **df2['Description'] = df2['Description'].astype(str) + str('/') +df2['path'].astype(str)** is used to concatenante the file path as you needed. Ofcourse you can do that for more than one entries **df2['Description'] = df2['Description'].astype(str) + str('/') +df2['path'].astype(str)+ str('/') +df2['somefield'].astype(str)** in this fashion

Comment: I think my comment was a bit confusing as I'm reading through it. For the same objectid there are multiple rows, therefore multiple descriptions. See this image: http://imgur.com/a/P0Pmq. So with the objectid: 100182 it should return the path of Car/3D Car Models/Truck and Heavy Vehicle/Production/International Truck/<Original Path from file1> Hope this is less confusing…

Comment: @kokozz - I made changes to my answer above. Your question wasn't exactly clear as to what you are expecting in the **description** column. This should give you the information you are looking for

Comment: Awesome. This works out perfectly. I managed to achieve a similar way using mysql queries but it still needs some work. Either way, thanks so much for help for a fellow canuck :)